# Get Wifi information on Windows (Cordova)

Tags: javascript, windows, cordova, cordova-plugins

I've been using https://github.com/parsonsmatt/WifiWizard to get Wifi information (specifically the connected SSID) on iOS and Android and it's been great. This plugin does not support Windows/Windows Phone however, is there a way I can see the name of the connected Wifi SSID on Windows or Windows Phone?

Comment: This is the only plugin which is close enough to your requirement - https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin

Comment: @Gandhi Thanks, looks like that will only get as far as telling me is Wifi available and not actually any information.

Comment: I saw that it mentioned something about wifi IDs but looks like returns just boolean, Guess no readymade plugins for windows then

Answer (score 0):

```
function getWifiSsid() {
    if (device.platform === 'windows') {
        let profile = Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.getInternetConnectionProfile();
        if (!profile) {
            throw 'No network connected';
        }
        if (profile.isWlanConnectionProfile && profile.wlanConnectionProfileDetails) {
            return profile.wlanConnectionProfileDetails.getConnectedSsid();
        } else {
            throw 'Wlan not connected';
        }
    } else {
        // todo
    }
}
```